# Prevent grep from exiting in case of nomatch

Tags: bash

Prevent grep returning an error when input doesn't match. I would like it to keep running and not exit with exit code: 1

```
set -euo pipefail
numbr_match=$(find logs/log_proj | grep "$name" | wc -l);
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: Don't use `grep` for this task. Use instead: `find logs/log_proj -name "*$name*"`, assuming the `$name` doesn't contain glob characters.

Comment: Don't use `set -e`.

Answer (score 1):

In this individual case, you should probably use

```
find logs/log_proj -name "*$name*" | wc -l
```

More generally, you can run `grep` in a subshell and trap the error.

```
find logs/log_proj | ( grep "$name" || true) | wc -l
```

... though of course `grep | wc -l` is separately [an antipattern](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#wc);

```
find logs/log_proj | grep -c "$name" || true
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using `-e` and `pipefail` when you don't want to have this behaviour. If your goal is just to treat exit code 2 (by grep) as error, but exit code 1 as no-error, you could write a wrapper script around `grep`, which you
call instead of *grep*:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script behaves exactly like grep, only
# that it returns exit code 0 if there are no
# matching lines
grep "$@"
rc=$?
exit $((rc == 1 ? 0 : rc))
```